# Windows 7 taskbar preview popup - How to keep it open?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, popups

In Windows 7, I would like to keep the thumbnail preview of an application in the taskbar open even when the mouse is not hovering over the icon in the taskbar. Is this possible and if so, how? Like Windows Media Player had a popup from the taskbar, but for other applications.

Comment: No answer provided for windows 7, only vista, so no, this question doesn't already have an answer.

Comment: Did you try the other answers? If so, what didn't work? Please be specific.